# How to use angular 1.3.4 and angular 2 together

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

I have already an application which is build on angular 1.3.4 and I want to change it to angular 2 but module wise.

lets say I've 5 modules on my page I want to migrate one module to angular 2 and other should work as it is like before with 1.3 so slowly slowly I can convert but till that it should not stop working.

I include both angular 2 and angular 1.3.4 libraries and it saying angular is not defined in console

Comment: to be honest, I wouldn't suggest you to install yet another plugin like *ng-upgrade* which add even more complexity to your codebase.
Instead, start isolating one module and migrate it as if were a single application with it's own services and routing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please read this blog:
http://angularjs.blogspot.nl/2015/08/angular-1-and-angular-2-coexistence.html

It explains how to run it together and how to finally upgrade to Angular 2.

The important thing of this link is:

> For this to work, four things need to interoperate between Angular 1
>   and Angular 2:
>
> - Dependency injection
> - Component nesting Transclusion
> - Change detection
>
> To make all this possible, we're building a library
>   named ng-upgrade. You'll include ng-upgrade and Angular 2 in your
>   existing Angular 1 app, and you'll be able to mix and match at will.

So you need ng-upgrade. See more information about that here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Answers should contain the information in them so they won't become useless when link rot kicks in.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, just added more context about the link.

Comment: I'm not using npm directly including link in src so is there any link or source from where I can download ng-upgrade too ?

Comment: It is part of AngularJs 2. See: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/upgrade/src/upgrade_adapter.ts