# Calling Angular 7 Code from AngularJS 1.x code

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, user-interface

One of my project requirement, I have to build the UI using Angular 7 on top of legacy codebase is AngularJS 1.x.

1) AngularJS is javascript but here Angular 7 is typescript.

How communication will happen through between these AngularJS and Angular.

Do we need to migrate legacy code to angular7 using Migration??

Please let me know the options to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate question. This other question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406678/how-to-use-angular-1-3-4-and-angular-2-together. But Personally I would suggest moving over to angular 2. Check the Angular website for help 'Upgrading from AngularJS to Angular'. But this depends on the size of the project

Answer (score 0):

Please follow https://angular.io/guide/upgrade. You need to downgrade the Angular 7's components or services to be use in AngularJS.

Something like this downgrading service to be use in AngularJS:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {}

/// downgrade parts
import { downgradeInjectable } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
declare const angular: any;

angular.module('angularJSApp').factory('myservice', downgradeInjectable(MyService));
```